# Laravel outputting a 'Redirecting to /URL/' message between page loads

Tags: laravel

No idea what has caused this, but my Laravel app is outputting a message between page loads, of 'Redirecting to a/url...' between page loads. It's doing it on my local MAMP set-up, and live on the Hostgator server. The routes and redirects otherwise work fine. It's just not a high quality experience for the end-user.

I don't recall changing any configs or anything, and toggling the debug config to true or false didn't seem to matter.

Ideas what might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post what those messages are?

Comment: Perhaps you should grep your code-base for `Redirecting to*`?

Comment: Wild guess: Laravel probably does this because headers have already been sent (either by a preceding/trailing blank before/after one of your script, or actual content) and proceeds with a redirect using javascript. Also, there has been recent discussions/commits about trailing slashes, I'd try to update laravel, and also adjust your links to have have trailing slashes if that'S what laravel tries to do.

Comment: Well, I just made an observation. I can narrow it down. These redirect messages happen whenever my app CRUD-interacts with the database (SQLite for this app).

Comment: I had a similar problem, on my case the problem was caused by Sublime Text 3 on Windows, I edited almost all the code on Windows e try sending/using on *unix system.
Checking my `route.php` file, the first character was a non-printable char.

Comment: May be I have same issue. I have checked placing ob_start() at the begining of controller code and  ob_get_contents() immediate before redirecting. but got '', Searching the solution.